# Regular idetifying repeatative patterns

Tags: python, regex

My data patterns looks like below,

```
t_hat_1
t_hat_2
t_hat_3
name
s_flower_1
s_flower_2
s_flower_3
s_flower_22
s_flower_23
address
```

I need to identify all the repeating matches like t_hat_1,2,3 & s_flower_1,2,3,22,23...I don't have the fixed number of repeatative items..for example:-hat will have [1-3] and flower[1-50]

What would be the most efficient way to identify these elements in Python regular expression..

Comment: Do you know in advance what the repeated patterns are, or do you know nothing about what will be repeated often and need to programatically discover common repetitions?

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` will return all matches:

```
import re

data = """
t_hat_1
t_hat_2
t_hat_3
name
s_flower_1
s_flower_2
s_flower_3
s_flower_22
s_flower_23
address
"""

flowers_patterns = re.findall('(s_flower_\d+)', data)
hat_patterns = re.findall('(t_hat_\d+)', data)
```